# Creating Rule Tile in Unity throws Errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I'm relatively new to Unity.

I'm making a 2D platformer, but whenever I create a Rule Tile object (Just by clicking *Right Click > Create > 2D > Tiles > Rule Tile*) it instantly throws the following Errors

```
- ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

- ArgumentException: Getting control 1's position in a group with only 1 controls when doing repaint
```

I'm using Unity Editor 2021.2.17f1 and TileMap Extras 2.2.1

(I tested with Unity Editor 2020.3.31f1 and TileMap Extras 1.8.1 and I still get the same Errors)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: How did you add Tile Map Extras to your Unity Project?

Comment: In 2021 Unity Editor Tile Map Extras are added by default. In the 2020 version I added it via enabling Pre-Release Packages in Package Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that despite the error messages, I can still start editing the Rule Tile, add rules and use them on the TileMap. Once I added everything I wanted and I ran the game the error messages disappeared.

Not sure what causes them (I still get these errors after every Rule Tile I create), but that's an easy "fix".